# How do I pass a variable between functions python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, parameter-passing

Here are my two functions:

```
def selectBadge(a):
    curItem = SelectBadgeView.focus()
        inter_var = SelectBadgeView.item(curItem)
        ListValues = inter_var['values']
        print(ListValues)
        SelectedBadge.set("Selected Badge: "+str(ListValues[0]))
        SelectedBadgeStr=str(ListValues[0])
        return SelectedBadgeStr

def selectScout(a,SelectedBadgeStr):
print(a)
if SelectedPatrol.get()==("Selected Patrol: Please Select A Patrol"):
    tk.messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Please select a Patrol")
    return
if SelectedBadge.get()==("Selected Badge: Please Select A Badge"):
    tk.messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Please select a Badge")
    return
print(SelectedBadgeStr)
return
```

I want to pass the variable `SelectedBadgeStr` from `selectBadge()` to `selectScout()`.

The variable `a` is a internal variable used by the tkinter treeview widget.

```
a = <ButtonRelease event state=Button1 num=1 x=144 y=39>
```

I have tried:

```
return SelectedBadgeStr
```

However this did not work.

The function is called by:

```
SelectScoutView.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selectScout)
```

Comment: Is there a code segment that makes the function calls? Have you tried calling `selectBadge()` and catching the value returned from that function call, then using that variable to call `selectScout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare `SelectedBadgeStr` as for example an empty string before defining the function `selectBadge(a)`?

So just declare it like:

`SelectedBadgeStr = ''`

`def selectBadge(a):
    curItem = SelectBadgeView.focus()
.
.
.`

It should work.

Comment: Well you see I was trying to avoid global variables.

Comment: I see... in this case try calling `selectScout` function by passing it the function `selectBadge(a)` as an argument: `selectScout(a,selectBadge(a))`

Comment: From your previous method I still get `TypeError: selectScout() missing 1 required positional argument: 'SelectedBadgeStr'` We can make it a global variable.

Comment: Are you sure that when you return 'SelectedBadgeStr' it is not noneType? Can you try printing it to make sure it actually has value?

Comment: It is a string as its defined as SelectedBadgeStr=("")

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shared global variable:

1. Declare the variable outside of the functions use:

   `SelectedBadgeStr = None`
2. At the beginning of the functions use:

   `global SelectedBadgeStr`

Whenever you use the variable now within the functions, you access the global variable